# How to use a variable from Bash into SQLPLUS?

Tags: bash, sqlplus

I'm trying to write a script which would accept the customer ID using BASH ( using a basic read command ) and then I want to use that BASH variable in my SQLPLUS query.  How can I do that ? I'm trying to use below format, but it is not working.

```
echo "Enter Customer ID :- ";
read Customer
sqlplus username\password@host
select first_name from customer where customer_id = $Customer;
quit
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would do:

```
echo "select first_name from customer where customer_id = $Customer;" | sqlplus username\password@host
```

If you want to run multiple queries, it is common to use a heredoc:

```
cat << EOF | sqlplus username\password@host
select first_name from customer where customer_id = $Customer;
select first_name from customer where customer_id = $Customer;
EOF
```

edited in response to query in comment:

to store the result of any command in a variable you can use process substitution.  `var=$( cmd )`.  In the heredoc case, the syntax is:

```
var=$( cat << EOF | sql...
query
query
EOF
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. it was very badly needed. Could you also suggest me a way to store the output of query in a variable ?